# Widgets in inlineformset_factory

Tags: django, django-forms

Hey i managed to make a inlineformset_factory but my widget in the Parent Model are not working although i have specified them in the `ModelForm` .

My forms.py :

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    post = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())

    class Meta:
        model  = Post
        fields = ['title', 'author','picture','post','draft','publish']

class PostVocabForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model  = PostVocab
        exclude = ()    

PostVocabInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Post,
    PostVocab,
    extra=1,
    exclude=(),
)
```

My CKEditorWidget is not working ....

My views.py:

```
class PostPostVocabCreate(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    # fields = ['title', 'author', 'picture', 'post', 'draft', 'publish']


    def get_redirect_url(self, pk):
        return reverse_lazy('blog:post_detail',
                            kwargs={'slug': pk},
                            )

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(PostPostVocabCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['postvocabs'] = PostVocabInlineFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['postvocabs'] = PostVocabInlineFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        postvocabs = context['postvocabs']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if postvocabs.is_valid():
                postvocabs.instance = self.object
                postvocabs.save()
        return super(PostPostVocabCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

I guess that my widget from the Parent model (Post) was overwritten while using a inlineformset_factory...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set widgets inside of inlineformset_factory.

```
PostVocabInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Post,
    PostVocab,
    extra=1,
    exclude=(),
    widgets={'post': CKEditorWidget()
)
```

From Django docs...inlineformset_factory uses modelformset_factory and passes most of its arguments to modelformset_factory. This means you can use the widgets parameter in much the same way as passing it to modelformset_factory.

```
AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(
...     Author, fields=('name', 'title'),
...     widgets={'name': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20})})`
```

Comment: class Meta:
        model  = Post
        fields = ['title', 'author','picture','post','draft','publish']
        widgets = {
            'post': forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget()),
        }
This did the trick and also i have forgot to add {{form.media}} in my template...